# how to insert values to multivalued attribute in sql with a primary key attribute in the table?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have created 2 tables as following

```
create table Room(
    roomID varchar(5),
    roomName varchar(20),
    price float,
    size varchar(10),
    beds varchar(15),
    numOfRooms int,
    numOfGuests int,
    constraint pk_room primary key(roomID)
);

create table Additional_room_info(
    roomId varchar(5),
    features varchar(20),
    constraint fk_room_add_ftrs foreign key(roomID) references Room(roomID)
);
```

And I want to make *roomId* in **Additional_room_info** the primary key of the table. I know that is not possible in this situation because the same *roomId* is repeatedly added to the table multiple times. Is there any other way to make a primary key without including *features* attribute?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
create table Additional_room_info(
    roomInfoId BIGINT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    roomId varchar(5),
    features varchar(20),
    constraint fk_room_add_ftrs foreign key(roomID) references Room(roomID)
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Add **id** to `Additional_room_info` as **primary key** with **auto increment** so you don't have to concern about it.

```
create table Additional_room_info(
    id INT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    roomId varchar(5),
    features varchar(20),
    constraint fk_room_add_ftrs foreign key(roomID) references Room(roomID)
);
```